# Custom Fonts used in react.js application are not visible after deployment on vercel

Tags: css, reactjs, fonts, vercel

```
  font-family: 'mona-sans-extrabold';
  src: url('./assets/fonts/MonaSans-ExtraBold.otf') format('truetype');
}
```

In my reactjs web application, I am using an custom font named "mona-sans" and the assets folder is in public directory.
the fonts is visible in local development but not visible after deploying o vercel

Comment: If you are using ReactJS and if your preferred font is `Mona-Sans` then you can add the font URL in your CSS file from a website like [this](https://www.cdnfonts.com/mona-sans.font)